# Grails 2.1 and CustomDateEditor doesn't seem to work

Tags: spring, date, grails, grails-2.1

I'm having trouble using CustomDateEditor in Grails 2.1.0

What I'm trying to achieve:

Date class is now rendered as 08/10/2013 00:00:00 CEST but I want to change the format to 08/10/2013 (dd/MM/yyyy format)

What I've done so far:

resource.groovy

```
beans = {
    customPropertyEditorRegistrar(myutil.CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar)
}
```

myutil.CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar

```
package myutil

import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistry
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomDateEditor
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

public class CustomPropertyEditorRegistrar implements PropertyEditorRegistrar {
    public void registerCustomEditors(PropertyEditorRegistry registry) {
        registry.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'), true)) //this doesn't work
        registry.registerCustomEditor(java.math.BigDecimal.class, new CurrencyPropertyEditor()) //this work so at least the registerCustomEditors method is invoked
    }
}
```

As you can see in my code there is a CurrencyPropertyEditor that work just fine so I'm confused here.. what's going on?

I've searched all around and it doesn't seems that my code is wrong but still it's not working.

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Comment: Uhm.. not sure, why 2 downvote.. is this question that bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scope f this is render the date in your own custom format, isn't it better to use the `g:formatDate` tag?
Something like:

```
 <g:formatDate format="dd/MM/yyyy" date="${date}"/>
```

Check [formatDate](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Tags/formatDate.html) documentation

Comment: Yes, that will be easy but I want to use the scaffold template so I can't change that AFAIK and besides of that the problem remains

Comment: Have you seen it in the docs  
_formatName (optional) - Look up format from the default MessageSource / ResourceBundle (i18n/*.properties file) with this key. If format and formatName are empty, format is looked up with 'default.date.format' key. Defaults to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss z' if the key not specified_ I never used it, but you can try to put that property in the config file, in this way you don't have to change nothing more than a property :) Hope it works

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem. Still I'm curious why I can use a property editor with BigDecimal but not with Date. I will accept your answer if nobody can answer that.

Comment: The problem is that the propertyEditor isn't for render stuff...it is used if you want to to put a Date into a input field...the property editor is an object that know how to transform an object (Date in this case) into a string (using the DateFormatter) and how to create a Date from a String. In the past I've used it with the domain classes of my application (Grails to it automatically). For this I wrote a propertyEditor that transform a domain class in a String (getting the id) and from a String create my domain object (querying the db with that id).

Comment: It isn't so easy to explain it in a comment. But if you are curious you can find a lot of stuff on the javadoc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyEditor.html and in the SpringMVC documentation ;)